# Setting up Python / Anaconda environment along with Visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda

I am trying to set up a dev environment for python and anaconda in a machine where Visual Studio 2017 is also installed.

The problem is, there are too many paths and duplicated installations. 
I uninstalled all python versions and removed the remained folders.
Then I used the Visual Studio installer tool and selected Python and Anaconda

The following folders appeared:

> > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64
> >
> > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64

These folders contain each one the Script subfolder, where some tools like the package manager pip resides.

Now when I use `python` and `pip` the found executable is the one under `Python36_64` but when I use anaconda it tries to use the python and packages from `Anaconda3_64` where the list of installed packages is differente and I would like to keep both installation folders up to date with the latest packages' versions.

How can I manage to synchronize both folders?